# obtaining a new image from an image using css data image

Tags: image, css

Here is my current image

```
url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAACXBIW…AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMkAAABHAQAA///exRMa9mY5qwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
```

I want the same image just using a different color. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the original image (or decode the one you have), modify it to suit your needs, and encode it again.

If the image was an svg, you would probably be able to tweak it (not sure if with pure css though). But the base64 encoded string has all the information regarding the given image, and you can't modify its color by simply using a css property.

However, you could probably apply some css filters (blur, black & white, etc), but I don't think that's what you are looking for.